# Visual indication of last focused item when application loses focus / alternative to IsKeyboardFocusWithin

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, focus, datatrigger

In an application with multiple panels or documents to interact with, one needs a clear indication of which area of the app has focus. Visual Studio itself is a good example of this.

The following [MCV Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is close to achieving the desired effect.
However, because it uses `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, the most recently focused item in the application is not maintained when the application itself loses focus.

**Desired Behavior:** The focused item indicated by blue "SelectedColor" is maintained when the application loses focus. Visual Studio does this.

**How can the indication of focus be maintained when the app loses focus?**

[image: Example Image]

- ## Code

  > *Note: There is no code-behind. This is the complete example.*

  ```
  <Window x:Class="TrackFocusMCVE.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
      Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>

      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverColor" Color="#FF1C97EA"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedColor" Color="#FF007ACC"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InactiveColor" Color="#19FFFFFF"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="#FF44454B"/>

      <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,15,5,7"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource InactiveColor}"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="TabControl.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}"/>
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>

      <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,2"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                      <Border Name="TabBorder" MinWidth="40" MinHeight="20"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                          <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                      </Border>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverColor}"/>
                          </MultiDataTrigger>
                          <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false" />
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource InactiveColor}"/>
                          </MultiDataTrigger>
                          <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}"/>
                          </MultiDataTrigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
      <Grid Background="DimGray">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TabControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tc1" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}">
              <TabItem Header="1" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
              <TabItem Header="2" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
              <TabItem Header="3" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
          </TabControl>
          <TabControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tc2" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}">
              <TabItem Header="4" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
              <TabItem Header="5" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
              <TabItem Header="6" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
          </TabControl>
      </Grid>
  </Window>
  ```

Comment: Isn't that selected item you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, but it must independently track selected item and focus. Otherwise you end up with two blue tabs at all times. Notice the light-grey indication of selected but not focused tab in the right tab control.

Comment: You could add an attached property LastSelected to your window and set that when either tabcontrol selecteditem changes. You could then use a datatrigger just on that.

Comment: @Andy Interesting. I will try to implement that and share if successful.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

You can make your focused tab stay blue when the window loses focus by changing your MultiDataTrigger Condition to use IsFocused instead of IsKeyboardFocusWithin like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

However, there is no straight forward way to know when a child of the TabControl is focused so that you can pain the border blue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does maintain the blue indication on the tab header. I see what you mean about the TabControl border though. I am holding out hope that someone will find an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @Andy 's advice, I created a `LastFocusedControl` property and trigger off of that.
<s>This solution works exactly as desired, albiet a tad verbose.</s>

Edit: This solution falls apart as soon as you allow focus to shift to a control inside the tab content. Leaving the answer here, so I can update it if I find a work-around.

### If anyone has a better solution, please share!

> **MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="TrackFocusMCVE.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
            Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
        <Window.Resources>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverColor" Color="#FF1C97EA"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedColor" Color="#FF007ACC"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InactiveColor" Color="#33FFFFFF"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="#FF44454B"/>

            <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,15,5,7"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource InactiveColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LastFocusedControl}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="TabControl.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    
            <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,15,5,7"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource InactiveColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LastFocusedControl}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="TabControl.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Border Name="TabBorder" MinWidth="40" MinHeight="20"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" 
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverColor}"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource InactiveColor}"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="TabBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid Background="DimGray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TabControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tc1" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}" GotFocus="Tc1_GotFocus" LostFocus="Tc1_LostFocus">
                <TabItem Header="1" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
                <TabItem Header="2" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
                <TabItem Header="3" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
            </TabControl>
            <TabControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tc2" Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle2}" GotFocus="Tc2_GotFocus" LostFocus="Tc2_LostFocus">
                <TabItem Header="4" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
                <TabItem Header="5" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
                <TabItem Header="6" Content="Tab Content" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"/>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

> **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace TrackFocusMCVE
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _lastFocusedControl = 0;
        public int LastFocusedControl
        {
            get { return _lastFocusedControl; }
            set { _lastFocusedControl = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LastFocusedControl)); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        
            TabItem item = (TabItem)tc1.Items[0];
            item.Focus(); // Default Focus
        }

        private void Tc1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { LastFocusedControl = 1; }
        private void Tc1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { LastFocusedControl = 0; }
        private void Tc2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { LastFocusedControl = 2; }
        private void Tc2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { LastFocusedControl = 0; }
   
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName) { 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }
}
```