# WPF, set focus on TabControl's content

Tags: wpf, focus, tabcontrol

I'd like to set focus to `TabControl`'s current selected `TabItem`'s content.

I'm binding items via `ItemsSource`, so I don't have simple access to `TabItem`s themselves;

I also cannot call `Focus()` on `TabControl`, because it focuses the `TabControl` itself instead of its content (for this one I did a crude, but effective check - made a DispatcherTimer, which emitted current focused item once a second).

Effectively I want to achieve the same effect as clicking on currently selected tab's header. How can I do that (not doing that quick&dirty by simulating the click, of course)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a specific TabItem gain focus on a TabControl without click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227132/how-can-i-make-a-specific-tabitem-gain-focus-on-a-tabcontrol-without-click-event)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Doesn't seem so. That question asks about selecting tab. I'm asking about focusing content of already selected tab.

Comment: Do you want to always set focus on the `TabItem` content on selection or just when you need to?

Comment: @Spook could you please provide your xaml of tab items ?

Comment: @Spook, isn't `((this.yourTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem).Content as UIElement).Focus();` working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your `TabControl` and override the `OnSelectionChanged` method.

```
protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Ignore this event on load.

    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        ((e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem)?.Content as UIElement)?.Focus();

    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
}
```